# Printing out elements in an array

Tags: arrays, c

Currently the code I have working is close but I'm having issues with printing the saved inputs. My output should look include the input elements above and then the elements reversed. Currently my code will only output the reversed array.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int main(void) {
       const int NUM_VALS = 4;
       int courseGrades[NUM_VALS];
       int i;
    
       for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; ++i) {
          scanf("%d", &(courseGrades[i]));
       }
       //above cannot be modified. Adding print statment below is 
       //close but only prints 4

       printf("%d \n", courseGrades[i];
       for (i = NUM_VALS - 1; i > 0; i--) {
           printf("%d ", courseGrades[i]);
        }
        printf("%d \n", courseGrades[i]);
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The line `printf("%d \n", courseGrades[i]);` is not inside a for loop, so it is printing just single line.

Comment: it was close. Putting that line in the loop doesn't work. The input is 7 9 10 11 so that needs to be printed and then the reverse below it, which is all I have now.

Comment: Try this: `i >= 0`

Answer (score 0):

Just add code for printing array

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; ++i) {
      printf("%d ", courseGrades[i]);
   }
printf("\n");
```

Comment: unfortunately I cant modify that portion of the code. I hate the site we use for the assignments

Comment: what part of code you can modify?

Comment: I can only modify after the last } from the first for loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the first for loop, the variable `i` is incremented to `NUM_VALS` which is `4`.
After that the line has printf(without closing brace)

```
printf("%d \n", courseGrades[i];
```

tries to prints `coursesGrade[4]` because of the reason I've mentioned. But there is no value at 4th index so it causes an undefined behaviour. So you need to remove that line, first.

In addition, as mentioned in comments above, you have an unneccessary line which is

```
printf("%d \n", courseGrades[i]);
```

If you insist on using it, then make it

```
printf("%d \n", courseGrades[0]);
```

OR

```
for (i = NUM_VALS - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // i>0 ==> i>=0
    printf("%d ", courseGrades[i]);
 }
```